# My macros is disabled when I open a Word document via VBA in Access?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I have made a special template for the Word documents I create via VBA in Access - the problem is that the macros in that template are disabled !

If I create a new document by clicking the template file itself ... it works nicely !

I have tried to replace my special template with the Normal.dotm and again create a Word document via mt access application ... then it works nicely !

The two templates (Normal.dotm and my special template) is stored in the same folder and in fact MY special template is just a copy of the Normal.dotm.

I have tried changing the settings in the "Security center" 1 chackmark at a time ... it makes NO difference at all !

I'm running Windows 10 fully updated and yesterday I reinstalled MSOffice 365 to see if that cures the problem - it didn't !

Please tell me what is wrong, I'm going nuts ...

By shifting the enviroment variable "SlgtSysWordSkabelon" I can quickly change between using "Normal.dotm" and "MySpecial.dotm" which in fact is just a copy of "Normal.dotm" placed side by side i the right folder.

Here is the code:

```
            Set WRDobj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'        WRDobj.Visible = False
        Set Doc = WRDobj.Documents.add(Environ("SlgtSysWordSkabelon"))
        Doc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "NotatID: " & Me.NotatID.Value & "-" & Me.Benævnelse.Value
        Doc.SaveAs Environ("SlægtHovedmappe") & "\" & "NOTAT_docs\" & Me.Sti_til_fil.Text, wdFormatDocumentDefault
        WRDobj.Quit
        Set Doc = Nothing
        Set WRDobj = Nothing
```

Comment: What code in Access vba are you using to create the new document? Please put this into your question.

Comment: @Charles Kenyon

Comment: @Charles Kenyon - I use this code:
        Set WRDobj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'        WRDobj.Visible = False
        Set Doc = WRDobj.Documents.add(Environ("SlgtSysWordSkabelon"))
        Doc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "NotatID: " & Me.NotatID.Value & "-" & Me.Benævnelse.Value
        Doc.SaveAs Environ("SlægtHovedmappe") & "\" & "NOTAT_docs\" & Me.Sti_til_fil.Text, wdFormatDocumentDefault
        WRDobj.Quit
        Set Doc = Nothing
        Set WRDobj = Nothing

Comment: Please put the code, formatted, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

So, in the Trust Center (File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings ...), you usually want to have the option set to "Disable all macros with notification". Whenever you now open a document that contains Macros and you haven't approved them before, a yellow bar should pop up and ask you if you want to allow Macros (which you want).
But it can happen, that Word still blocks the Macros in this document. In such a case, close the document, do a right-click on it and open the properties. In the general tab at the bottom, there you will find a text box which should say something like "allow". Although the attached image contains German text, it should be helpful for you for locating this checkbox. Once that is checked, the Macros should work.

[image: File properties dialog window]

Comment: Been there done that - makes no difference and I have NOT the shown checkbox in my properties for the file :-(